# Neo4j: difference between tinkerpop gremlin and aurelius gremlin

Tags: neo4j, gremlin, tinkerpop

as I was wandering in the Web looking for a Gremlin implementation for Neo4j I found these two possible solutions:

1. https://github.com/thinkaurelius/neo4j-gremlin-plugin
2. http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#neo4j-gremlin

Does anybody know what is the difference between the two in practice? 
I saw that 1. is a Neo4j plugin while it's not really clear to me what the second is, and if it would lock the entire database thus not allowing other connections (I noticed that it requires the path to the data folder).

Which one is preferred in the neo4j community?

Cheers,

Alberto

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure there's really a difference as there isn't a direct comparison to be made.  The second link is to the TinkerPop project and specifically to the Neo4j implementation of TinkerPop APIs.  It runs in an embedded mode and does not yet have support for HA (though we hope to have that soon).  The Neo4j implementation can be run in [Gremlin Server](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#gremlin-server) which let's you send Gremlin to it as a REST, websockets, etc endpoint.

The project in the first link you provided uses that implementation to allow you to send Gremlin to Neo4j Server - so the first project depends on the second.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @stephen. Since I saw that you're a member of Aurelius in Github, do you know if neo4j-gremlin-plugin supports neo4j 2.2.7? I've followed the instructions reported in the project page but I get this error: `Starting Neo4j Server failed: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-e1dd969@ae4c07fc==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false` Do you know, by chance, what's going on?

Comment: There are currently some dependency issues that prevent me from bumping the versions. The latest supported Neo4j version is 2.2.1, hence that's the one you should use.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz, I've posted a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33807044/gremlin-on-neo4j-2-2-7), will you comment on that? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your rule of thumb should be activity in the source code.

- neo4j-gremlin-plugin has 3 commits this year - https://github.com/thinkaurelius/neo4j-gremlin-plugin/commits/master
- tikerpop is much more active - https://github.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/commits/master/neo4j-gremlin/src/main/java/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/neo4j

**neo4j-gremlin-plugin**

Extending existing Neo4j server with support for Gremlin Query Language.

**TinkerPop Neo4j-Gremlin**

Extending Gremlin console with support for Neo4j server.