# Gremlin on Neo4j 2.2.7

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

I need to incorporate the possibility of sending Gremlin scripts to my Neo4j 2.2.7 DB so I tried to install the [thinkaurelius neo4j plugin](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/neo4j-gremlin-plugin) by using one of the prebuilt releases.

Unfortunately I guess those releases were built for older Neo4j versions (2.1.6) and, as a result, I got this error when I tried to start Neo4j from my Windows machine with Java 8:

```
Starting Neo4j Server failed: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-e1dd969@ae4c07fc==org.neo4j.server.web.‌​NeoServletContainer,-1,false
```

To experiment a bit with the Gremlin language I tried to connect to my DB from the [gremlin console](http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/docs/3.0.2-incubating/#neo4j-gremlin) (the DB wasn't used by any other process) but, when I run `graph = Neo4jGraph.open('<path to my db>')` the console stopped responding (there was no new prompt appearing).

Does anybody know what I could do to run some Gremlin script on my database?

Comment: For now an older version of Neo4j would be your best bet. I just contacted Neo4j to see if we can find a solution to bump the version numbers (it's not as easy as it sounds, since we're having some license conflicts between TinkerPop and Neo4j).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @DanielKuppitz. I've installed Neo4j 2.1.6 and re-done the procedure but the message keeps on popping up. Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Can you show the actual request that triggers the exception? Unfortunately I have no Windows test environment and everything appears to run fine under Linux.

Comment: FYI: I just released a new version of the plugin that works with Neo4j 2.3.1 and TP 3.1.0. Successfully tested in my Linux environment.

Comment: Hi @DanielKuppitz, sorry for the late answer. I couldn't catch the request as the error happened while starting neo4j. I'll try the new version you released today. Thanks a lot for letting me know :)

Comment: unfortunately I keep on getting the same error: `Starting Neo4j failed: org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer-338a3a1c@efc50f3d==org.neo4j.server.web.NeoServletContainer,-1,false`. I don't know where to find more specific information: I tried to launch the application also with `java -jar` but I did not get any additional information on the error :(

Comment: Oh, then it doesn't really seem to be related to the plugin. Does Neo4j start properly if you comment out the plugin configuration section? If so, did you double check, that you don't have a typo in your configuration?

Comment: @DanielKuppitz, thanks for helping. Yes, if I comment the plugins section Neo4j starts. Here is the line I've added: `org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=com.thinkaurelius.neo4j.plugins=/tp`. As reported in the github repo I extracted the content of the prebuilt releas in `$NEO4J_HOME/plugins/gremlin-plugin`. I have Java 8 installed in my system, if this can help.

Comment: Update: I've moved all the content of the release to the `plugins` folder and I got an unsupported major.minor version 52.0 exception. I'll try to recompile the plugin by using Java7...

Comment: Note that TP3 requires Java8. The unsupported mijor.minor version error suggests that your environment isn't set up properly. It usually only occurs when you try to load Java8 libs using a Java7 (or lower) JVM.

Comment: I'll double, check. For the moment i'm using the groovy console. Cheers!

Comment: `java -version` tells me I have Java 1.8.0_66. I also double check my `Path` and `JAVA_HOME` variables, as well as the links in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` and they all point to the right directory. I wonder which JVM is actually executing the extension at this point...

Comment: ah, maybe this can help: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-plugins.html "Whilst Neo4j is tested to run on JVM 8, Neo4j server is currently compiled using JDK 7, to ensure compatibility for JVM 7 deployments. When compiling plugins for Neo4j Server, we strongly recommend using JDK 7 also."